# Export Excel Worksheets (from list of sheet names) to PDF with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a VBA macro to export Worksheets to a single PDF based on a list of sheet names. The list of these names are in the range `A22:A56` on **Sheet1**.

Comment: Start with the macro recorder and then work with that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code firstly hides the sheets of the Workbook that aren't in the list, then it exports all visible sheets to a single PDF file and finally unhides all hidden sheets.

Set the correct **path** and **list range** before running it.

```
Sub select_sheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim path As String

'CONFIG
'----------------
path = "/Users/user/Desktop/MyFileName.pdf" 'set path to save file
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A22:A56") 'set list range
'----------------

'hide sheets that aren't in the list
For Each ws In Worksheets

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, ws.Name) = 0 Then
        Sheets(ws.Name).Visible = False
    End If
    
Next
    
'export workbook to PDF
Call export_pdf(path)
    
'unhide all sheets
For Each ws In Worksheets
    Sheets(ws.Name).Visible = True
Next
    
End Sub

Sub export_pdf(path As String)

    ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=path, _
    Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great. How can I re-write the `path` string to always export the pdf to the same folder as the Workbook?

Comment: @Bberghy I'm glad it worked. You could do something like `path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/MyFileName.pdf" `

Comment: @Bberghy what should I change if I want to save the results as xlsx, not pdf?